# svn can't connect to host 'localhost'

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, localhost, trac

I started two days ago to set up an SVN environment on my local machine (win).

I installed subversion + Tortoise SVN two days ago and created the first test project. Opening the link `svn://localhost` in my browser showed the Repository Browser with my test project having the folders tags, branches and trunk inside (which was great).

Last night I also decided to install Trac. After installing python 2.5, I've created a new environment to test it. Of course, doing it for the first time, I made some mistakes and had to redo the whole process, but I finally succeeded creating that test environment.

Well, after figuring out how I should keep the environments, I created another one and of course the svn repo for it and synchronized them. Also, accessing `http://locallhost:8000/my_project_path works fine. But now, when I try to access`svn://localhost` from the Repository Browser window, all I get is the message

```
Can't connect to host localhost: 
No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

I've tried to start the server with this command

```
svnserve --daemon --root "path/to/my/repo
```

but after executing it I don't get any response and I have to ctrl+break to be able to enter another command.

I really don't know what the problem it, this being the first time installing them and trying to make them work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you start the Subversion server like this then having a blank window is normal, and the server is probably up and running. You only see something in the window if there is an error. You should then try the Tortoise Repo Browser to connect to svn://localhost/ and you should be good to go.

You can run it like this with the server window just left open, but normally you'll install as a service if you're going to use the server a lot.

Comment: yes, i think this was the problem, i started again svnserve and immediately opened svn://localhost and i'm not getting any error. all i have to do now is to verify the repo directory. Thank you all for the answers :)

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem on Windows Vista this morning and thought I would share the cause in case it helps anyone that finds this old question.

In my case, the Subversion service failed to start.  There was an entry in the System event log

> A timeout was reached (30000
>   milliseconds) while waiting for the
>   Subversion Repository (UNC) service to
>   connect.

For some reason Subversion had timed out trying to start up.

The solution was as simple as trying to start the service again.